# Is it possible to apply group membership when authenticating a user with django-mama-cas and django-cas-ng?

Tags: python, django, cas

I am using django-mama-cas (2.4.0) and django-cas-ng (3.5.10) to manage user authorisation (single sign on, single log off, group membership) across a few django (1.11) projects. I am able to apply user attributes  (first_name, last_name, email address) from the cas server to the cas-ng clients using
the callback 'mama_cas.callbacks.user_name_attributes' in mama-cas and setting CAS_APPLY_ATTRIBUTES_TO_USER = True on my cas-ng clients.

On my mama-cas server, I also add the user to a number of groups (snippet below) which I want to then apply to the users on the cas-ng clients.

```
group = Group.objects.get(name=groupname)
user.groups.add(group)
```

However, when I try using the callback 'mama_cas.callbacks.user_model_attributes' in mama-cas none of the group memberships are applied to my clients (I check this via the admin interface and via the django shell).

Is applying group membership from mama-cas to cas-ng possible or am I doing something wrong? If it's not possible my next best idea was to create some boolean custom user attributes, i.e. user.is_member_groupA etc but would welcome advice.

Thanks in advance

Update 1:
From the mama-cas callbacks.py I see that only fields within user._meta_fields are added to the dict of attributes returned and that user.groups etc are not included here. From this I presume that group memberships are not intended to be applied from mama-cas to cas-ng as I am trying?

Answer (score 1):

For posterity:

If you're using a virtual environment, you can find and edit the callbacks.py somewhere similiar to *lib/python3.10/site-packages/mama_cas*.

You can access the attributes returned by the custom functions in callbacks.py through *request.session['attributes']* .

If someone can leave a link to official docs describing these, it would be appreciated, because I just found out about these by mere chance.

In my case, I also just created a custom user model with a groups or permissions field in django-mama-cas server then accessed the values in the django-cas-ng client through request.session['attributes']. Although I feel like there's a better solution out there.